# Epsilon-Delta Proof of $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt[3]{x}=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Just need to check if $$\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt[3]{x}=0$$ using the epsilon-delta definition of limits is something like $\delta < \epsilon/3$. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Proof:** Let $ \epsilon >0 $ and $ x\in [0,\infty) $. Choose $ \delta =\epsilon ^{3} $. Then $ \delta >0 $. Suppose $ 0<|x|<\delta $. Then we have $ 0<x<\delta =\epsilon ^{3} $. Hence $ 0<\sqrt[3]{x}<\epsilon $. Thus $ |\sqrt[3]{x}-0|<\epsilon $.

Therefore for each $ \epsilon >0 $ and for each $ x\in [0,\infty) $, there exists  $ \delta >0 $ such that if $ 0<|x|<\delta $ then $ |\sqrt[3]{x}-0|<\epsilon $. So $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt[3]{x}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Choose $\delta < \epsilon^3$ and use the fact that $[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is increasing.